# How can I create a .exe-File of a python programm consisting out of several classes located in different files?

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

after several hours of reasearing I havent found a helpful answer to this question on the Internet. I have just seen several solutions about how to convert a single python-file into a .exe-file using pyinstaller.

About my programm: Its i a window application in python, therefore i have used the tkinter-library. The whole program is about restoring and documenting my income an spendings over a year, so that I have an overview over my finances. For that I have separated the program in two big folders[enter image description here][1]. One is called data for handeling all the numbers and other significant information and one is called gui for storing the files about the window and its different frames. In data i have different classes, e.g. a class that represents a year, one that represents a month, etc. As already mentiond, in gui you can find the main window and the different frames where the data is shown and can be manipulated. On top of that i have placed the file where i am storing the data in  gui. The whole program is started from the main.py which is in none of the named folders.

I have already tried just converting the main.py which failed instantly. Next I tried the option in auto-py-to-exe where you can add additional files. There i have added the gui and the data folders but it wasnt successful either.

On top information: I have programed in PyCharm, so thats why there are extra folders like .idea etc.

I hope I have explained my problem good enough and out there is somebody that can help me.If you still have question feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance

wotex

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i have found a solution by myself. First you have to add the folders gui and data in the auto py to exe program, then you have to add all the different files that are in these folders(e.g. all the files with the classes or the text file).
But take care to import all libraries you use in your program in in main.py(the file you want to convert). Otherwise auto-py-to-exe wont convert these libraries and the program doesnt work. Maybe there is also another solution, but this is the only one that works with me.

Greetings

wotex

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).